# Kernel runs significantly slower after irrelevant codes are added

Tags: opencl

I'm using OpenCL to implement GEMM on Adreno GPU. The general idea is to divide result matrix C into rectangular pieces, and each work item is responsible to calculate one of them. My original code generally looks like below:

```
__kernel void simple_gemm(const __global float4* A,
                          __read_only image2d_t B,
                          __global float4* C)
{
    // some code to calculate the corresponding piece of matrix C
}
```

The original kernel assumes that matrix C can be perfectly divided into whole pieces, and it runs at maximum of **50 GFLOPS** on my device. Then I add codes to support cases when there's some remainder on the border of C when divided into pieces, and my second kernel looks like this:

```
__kernel void gemm(const __global float4* A,
                   __read_only image2d_t B,
                   __global float4* C)
{
    if (corresponding_piece_not_on_border)
    {
        // some code to calculate a whole piece of matrix C
    }
    else
    {
        // some code to calculate a partial piece of matrix C
    }
}
```

However, when I go back to test original cases (that is, there is no border cases, hence the codes in the else are never executed), I find that my kernel's performance has dropped down to about **30 GFLOPS**, which is not expected. I've double checked that my kernel never reaches codes in the `else` block, which means the second kernel would be logically identical to the first one when fed with original test data.

(I tried to get the "low level code" of my kernel to see if there's something wrong, but it seems that Qualcomm haven't published their low level specs)

So, what could be the problem in my case? Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Could the compiler be computing both if and else parts and assigning only the result similarly to cpu SIMD style ternary? Does it get even slower(15 Gflops) if you make it 3 cases?

Comment: How do you compute "corresponding_piece_not_on_border"? Does it introduce extra memory accesses? Are you 100% sure the else code does never get executed? Even a 0.1% of the times entering will lead to all workers entering the code.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik actually the codes I omitted are quite time-costing, so I don't think the compiler would do something silly like this. Also I've tried to add a third block but the speed remains the same as two blocks. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DarkZeros It's just a simple formula using global and local id and some constant parameters. I've been editing my code back and forth, and the efficiency didn't fluctuate drastically like this. I used printf statement to make sure the second block hasn't been executed, since I don't know better ways to check this. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you're running into register allocation problems? All `private` variables (i.e. local variables in kernels/functions which aren't marked `local`) on all possible execution paths are typically statically allocated in the GPU's register file. If your rare execution path uses a lot of private variables, you'll pay the price for them even if the code never runs. Register pressure reduces thread occupancy/parallelism, potentially reducing throughput. Try to make the rare code use less of the register file and see if that helps. (Or use implementation-specific tooling to check.)

Comment: NB: the register allocation issue can also apply to constants (literal or symbolic) as far as I'm aware, although the effect is typically less severe as they're allocated per execution unit, not per thread.

Comment: @pmdj You're probably right. I did some further experiments and found that for some reason my compiler tends to allocate dedicated registers to both `if` and `else` code block, and this happens even if I declare all the temporary variables out side those two blocks. I believe the buggy compiler is to blame, or is this how it works on GPU?